# Hawking vs Susskind Information Paradox PBS Nova TV show - nowhere to be found

Tags: cosmology, specific-reference

I remember there was an awesome Nova episode, **at least 10 years ago**, where there was a battle in which Susskind ridiculed Hawking for his silly theory of violation of the Conservation of Information law, when it comes to Super Massive Black Holes.

For the life of me, I cannot find any trace of this documentary masterpiece anywhere.

I am guessing that it was wiped off the face of the earth, or as Hawking would put it, "sent to a different universe" :), because it was oh so politically incorrect and especially since Hawking is the "progressive" deity of Theoretical Physics.

Looking for help in finding...

EDIT:  The narrative of this show was that Hawking held the theoretical physics community in a state of cult of personality worship for 20 years, until Susskind dethroned him.  After a year or so of hiding, Hawking came back to defend his theory with "information going to another universe", which according to the narrator, "bemused" the theoretical physics community.

This narrative has since been "revised" to fit the "modern" political atmosphere which is based on Cultural Marxism, hence it would not be surprising if a deliberate effort was made to "revise history" by removing any reference to the existence of this controversial video.  And yes, "progressives" are good at revising history to fit their agenda

And yes also, this question is indeed relevant to this forum, as politics are known to taint and distort scientific research and the establishment of truth.

Comment: This isn't really about physics concepts, but try searching YouTube because Susskind often lectured about his thoughts on Hawking's ideas.  Keep in mind that Susskind is a one-man sarcasm machine and joked about everything.  No-one (apart from you), including I imagine Stephen Hawking, would regard Susskind's remarks as "ridicule" or "politically incorrect", especially as Hawking was one of the few people on Earth able argue with Susskind at his own level.  Friendly rivalry - nothing more.  The idea of a conspiracy theory to hide their friendly disagreement is ludicrous.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about physics

Comment: @JohnRennie: why the answer to this question could not provide interesting physics? Maybe questions on "specific-reference" are  forbidden by some rule? (It is not a polemic question, just to know).

Comment: @GiorgioP a question about the information paradox would be fine (though I'm sure this has been asked before). This isn't a question about the information paradox - it's asking where to find a TV programme.

Comment: @JohnRennie: ok, I understand. But this implies that also questions on conventional bibliographic reference materials (books, journals) are not fine?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the [tag:specific-reference] policy only covers questions regarding the identification, not of materials, not their location.

Comment: If the [physics.se] community decides this question isn't a good fit, we might migrate it to [movies.se].

Comment: @StephenG, actually, the narrator made a mockery out of hawking (and rightfully so) towards the end, when Hawking came back after a year or so, concocting  a way to redeem his "throne" after Susskind destroyed it.  Hawking called a conference and announced that Susskind was right but he (Hawking) was right also.  He stated that although information does not get destroyed, it does not really get preserved either, because it goes to another universe.  The narrator stated that the audience was "bemused".  I can imagine that you would be offended by this show.

Comment: @LastTribunal We're clearly not going to agree.  You hear "mock" and "ridicule", I certainly never have.  We must agree to differ.

Comment: @StephenG, I am not seeking an agreement with you.  I am seeking info that you don't have. No need to comment further

Comment: @Chris, I agree, subscribers/purveyors of Cultural Marxism will encourage me to suppress mentions of such, before they will vote to shut down dissent

Answer (score 1):

Ten years ago, Susskind published [The Black Hole War: My Battle with Stephen Hawking to Make the World Safe for Quantum Mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Black_Hole_War), a dead-tree book on the subject you describe. The book-promotion business these days includes as many media appearances as the author and the publisher can manage, so it's reasonable to think that Susskind would have appeared in public many times that year, including on television. Here's [a non-televised appearance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KR3Msi1YeXQ) that's probably typical.

Looking at NOVA's archives directly finds a [2013 web article](https://www.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/article/do-black-holes-destroy-information/), but not a television episode featuring either scientist.

Searching the IMDB, it doesn't appear that [Susskind](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm1475503/?ref_=fn_nm_nm_10) and [Hawking](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0370071/?ref_=nm_wrk) have appeared on-screen together --- or at least if they have, it hasn't yet been found and catalogued by the fastidious community that maintains that database.  The closest seems to be that both appeared in a documentary series called [Through the Wormhole](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1513168/?ref_=nm_flmg_arf_22), with Susskind in [The Riddle of Black Holes (2010)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1669757/?ref_=nm_flmg_slf_6), and Hawking in [What is Nothing? (2012)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2196792/?ref_=nm_flmg_arf_22).

Comment: None of these references lead to this show I am referring to. I did all the google and Nova archives stuff already.  This is the point I made in the question: the show has been erased from existence.

Comment: This show was created way before Morgan became the face of "intellect" on MSM

Comment: *the show has been erased from existence* Or, much, much more likely you either don't recall it correctly, or it was removed from public access because the **copyright holders** wanted to (quite reasonably) protect their assets from piracy, or you misinterpret what you saw/remember.  Or a combination of those.  Your belief in a grand conspiracy (of global proportions) beggars belief.

Comment: @StephenG, you worry too much about what I may or may not believe instead of providing the info that I seek, which you don't have.  No need to keep making pointless comments